# Laravel 4 seeding class Sentry not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm following a tutorial from [Code Forest](http://www.codeforest.net/laravel4-simple-website-with-backend-1) an when using `php artisan db:seed`, I get this error:

PHP Fatal Error: Class 'Sentry' not found in /var/www/app/database/seeds/SentrySeeder.php on line 13

here is SentrySeeder.php :

```
<?php

use App\Models\User;

class SentrySeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->delete();
    DB::table('groups')->delete();
    DB::table('users_groups')->delete();

    Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
        'email'       => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password'    => "admin",
        'first_name'  => 'John',
        'last_name'   => 'McClane',
        'activated'   => 1,
    ));

    Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
        'name'        => 'Admin',
        'permissions' => array('admin' => 1),
    ));

    // Assign user permissions
    $adminUser  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('admin@admin.com');
    $adminGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Admin');
    $adminUser->addGroup($adminGroup);
    }

}
```

And here is [User model](https://github.com/bstrahija/l4-site-tutorial/blob/master/app/models/User.php)

Sentry has been added to apps under providers
What Am i missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you added the Facade for Sentry?

add

```
'Sentry' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry',
```

to the array of facades in config/app.php

Comment: That was it. It was optional in the documentation, but should be more recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider' to the list of service providers in app/config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

I had to add both in app/config/app.php file:

1.

> 'Sentry' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry',

to the: 'aliases' => array(

AND

2.

> Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider,

to the: 'providers' => array(